# wpf Listview with textbox error

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a listview with a gridview cell template, as a textbox.

I can change the itemssource in the ui at runtime, but I can't do it, in code behind..

Please any ideas why would be a appreciated.

it's bound to a custom list.

this is my code so far:

Xaml template.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="GridBlockStyle">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, ConverterParameter=False}" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="GridEditStyle">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, ConverterParameter=True}" />
</Style>
<DataTemplate x:Key="txt_Field" DataType="{x:Type GridViewColumn}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=txt}" Style="{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=txt}"/>
            </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
DataTemplate t_txt = (DataTemplate)window.FindResource("txt_Field");
gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "txt", CellTemplate = t_txt });
```

it updates the itemssource and as soon as the foreach loops are done the Entries are being overriden to null.

```
try
{
      foreach (Items1 item in TempList)
      {
           foreach (Items1 item2 in list)
           {
                if (item.num == item2.num)
                {
                      item2.txt = item.txt;
                }
           }
     }
     listview.Items.Refresh();

}
catch { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I still want to know why it happent..

this is the solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TempList.Count; i++)
{
    if (Order_TempList[i].txt == ((Items1)listview.SelectedItem).txt)
    {
        ((Items1)listview.SelectedItem).txt = Order_TempList[i].txt;
        i = TempList.Count;
    }
}
```

I can see the error very clearly now.
It's because there is two `lists` and the `visual list` (listview.Items) is being updated and not the `physical list` (TempList).